# How to determine what type a deserialized json string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a WebApi that returns a `BadRequest` and the content can be one of 3 different types of exceptions (inherited from `Exception`).

The client has to determine which type of exception it is and handle it accordingly. Currently I'm doing:

```
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
{
    var ex = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
}
```

But how can I get the exact type I need?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that `response.Content` contains a serialized exception that was raised on the server and you're wanting to deal with it on the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you did the JSON serialization on serverside like this

```
try {
....
catch (SomeExceptionType ex)
    var resultbody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex);
}
```

Then your resultbody will look something like this

```
{
  "ClassName": "your.namespace.SomeExceptionType",
  "Message": "foo bar",
  "Data": null,
  "InnerException": null,
  "HelpURL": null,
  "StackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
  "ExceptionMethod": null,
  "HResult": -2146233088,
  "Source": null,
  "WatsonBuckets": null
}
```

From that you can restore the exception like this

```
JObject exJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(exString);
Type t = Type.GetType(exJson.Value<string>("ClassName"));
var ex = exJson.ToObject(t);
```

**EDIT**

If you have a limited range of possiblities for the exception type, you can of course also do this

```
switch (exJson.Value<string>("ClassName")) {
    case "your.namespace.SomeExceptionType":
        {
            SomeExceptionType ex = exJson.ToObject<SomeExceptionType>();
        }
        break;
    case "your.namespace.OtherExceptionType":
        {
            OtherExceptionType ex = exJson.ToObject<OtherExceptionType>();
        }
        break;
    default:
        {
            Exception ex = exJson.ToObject<Exception>();
        }
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What i understand from your question is that from Api you will get Http status code BadRequest and it's result will contains C# Exception which is inherited from Exception class.

If you parse this line

```
var ex = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

it will parse from JSON to Object class. 
But the content will be the exception thrown from the web api therefore you cannot parse the content into Exception object.

Better way to check string contains

```
    String res= response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.toString();
    if(res.Contains("Type1Exeption")){
    throw new Type1Exception()
    }
else if(res.Contains("Type2Exeption")){
    throw new Type2Exception()
    }
else{
throw new Type3Exception()
}
```